# Akka.NET TestKit getting timeout error

Tags: c#, akka.net, akka-testkit

I am testing with NUnit. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class ZipActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public ZipActor()
    {
        Receive<ZipMessage>(message => HandleZipMessage(message));
    }

    private void HandleZipMessage(ZipMessage message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Received: {0} for {1}", typeof(ZipMessage).Name, message.SourceFolderPath));
    }
}

public class ZipMessage
{
    public readonly string SourceFolderPath;

    public ZipMessage(string sourceFolderPath)
    {
        SourceFolderPath = sourceFolderPath;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class ZipActorTests : TestKit
{
    [Test]
    public void ZipActor_WhenSentZipMessage_ShouldReceiveZipMessage()
    {
        var actor = Sys.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new ZipActor()));
        string path = "some path";

        actor.Tell(new ZipMessage(path));

        ExpectMsg<ZipMessage>();
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

Failed: Timeout 00:00:03 while waiting for a message of type CloudBackupActors.Messages.ZipMessage

This is what I get in NUnit'sconsole output.
Received: ZipMessage for some path
[WARNING][16/11/2015 18:46:37][Thread 0012][akka://test/user] DeadLetter from [akka://test/user] to [akka://test/user]: : [akka://test/user/$b], ExistenceConfirmed=True, AddressTerminated=False>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I got the wrong end of the stick here and it makes sense when I actually add the end line of HandleZipMessage that I had missed out. My test is in fact analogous to this post - [Testing Akka.NET's Context.Parent with TestKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895751/testing-akka-nets-context-parent-with-testkit?rq=1). So what I needed to do is this, which works. :)

```
public class ZipActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public ZipActor()
    {
        Receive<ZipMessage>(message => HandleZipMessage(message));
    }

    private void HandleZipMessage(ZipMessage message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Received: {0} for {1}", typeof(ZipMessage).Name, message.SourceFolderPath));
        // TODO: Zip operations
        Context.Parent.Tell(new IncrementFolderCountMessage());
    }
}

public class ZipMessage
{
    public readonly string SourceFolderPath;

    public ZipMessage(string sourceFolderPath)
    {
        SourceFolderPath = sourceFolderPath;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class ZipActorTests : TestKit
{
    [Test]
    public void ZipActor_WhenReceivedZip_ShouldIncrementFolderCount()
    {
        // Arrange
        // (make ZipActor child of TestActor)
        var props = Props.Create(() => new ZipActor());
        var actor = ActorOfAsTestActorRef<ZipActor>(props, TestActor);

        string path = "some path";

        // Act
        actor.Tell(new ZipMessage(path));

        // Assert
        ExpectMsg<IncrementFolderCountMessage>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding which actor is the subject of `ExpectMsg()`. The `ExpectMsg` call is being called on the `TestActor`, which is the default/implicit sender of all messages in `TestKit` tests.

So the error is because you are telling the `TestKit` that the `TestActor` should expect a `ZipMessage`. To be clear, as written, is saying that the `TestActor` should get a `ZipMessage`. It is not saying that the `ZipActor` should get that message. The timeout you are hitting is the default :03 timeout that the `TestActor` applies to its `ExpectMsg` call.

To make the test pass as it's set up now, you'd need to `Sender.Tell(new ZipMessage("foopath"))` from inside the `ZipActor`.

In all fairness to you, the project docs for the `TestKit` are currently missing (as of 11/16/15). We're in the middle of writing them now and they should be published next week.

For now I suggest you check out [this thorough intro to the TestKit](https://petabridge.com/blog/how-to-unit-test-akkadotnet-actors-akka-testkit/) (disclosure: I wrote it). I think it will give you a very solid understanding of how the `TestKit` actually works.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I did read your post but I didn't read it carefully enough! I have now posted my own solution. :)